# Pagination repeater has an active class that i must move when pagination button clicked

Tags: angularjs, pagination

Take the following pagination html and repeater:

```
<ul id="ProductListPagination" class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li>

    <li ng-repeat="n in PageCount" ng-class="{active: n==1}"><a ng-click="Paginate( n )"  href="#"><% n %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I go about moving the `active` class on the repeater when one of the pagination buttons are pressed... Is there a built in angular way?...

**context:**

[image]

---

*If there is no built in way in angular, how do I pass the dom element through to the `Paginate( n )` function?*

I have the receiving function:

```
$scope.Paginate = function( obj, page ){

    // Remove currently active button's active class
    $( "#ProductListPagination li.active" ).each( function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
    } ); 
    // Add to element just clicked on
    $( obj ).parent().addClass( "active" );
    ...

}
```

And the html to go with that, you'll see I tried passing in `this`.

```
<li style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="n in PageCount" ng-class="{active: n==1}"><a ng-click="Paginate( this, n )"  href="#"><% n %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

But that doesn't work as this, is not a dom element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Directives**

This could be done with Directives, these allow you to define custom markup ie. an element, an attribute name, it even can hook onto class names. Then from that you can attach all sorts of stuff.

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-first-directive

So you could make a "Pagination" directive.

and that would then be used something like:

`<my-pagination pages="arrayInScope">`

You can then provide an external template or even a string of markup (eww) for what needs to be either IN this element or to replace this element.

**Another Solution**

But this is a quick way and I guess it doesn't really need any more over complicating anyway.

[Example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/cjonasw/pen/3837fc2f7fade7370966febc36091d48/)

From the markup I am calling the paginate function parsing ng-repeat's provided `$index`. In the paginate function in the js i then set it.

As angular digests this: `ng-class="{ active : page == current }"` will then re-evaluate.

But if you need access to the element for some reason then use directives. jQuery is best avoided when using Angular, if it is just a class change or a visibility toggle etc. then its best to let Angular do it for ya'

Hope that helps.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks. I was certainly over complicating it in my head.